# Is there a way in java to check if a string is a part from many strings in a list

Tags: java

Say I have a list of file names with different extensions:

```
ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList("filename1.txt", "filename2.txt", "filename2.xml", "filename2.csv", "filename3");
```

and I would like to check (ideally also count occurrences) if a certain filename exists regardless of the extension.

So I would like to check if `filename2` exists in the list. If I use `Collections.frequency` or `contains()` it only works with the full name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not out of the box. You have a `String` list. Java doesn't know that these happen to be file names. You'd have to define the logic to parse the file names. That in turn may need to take the file system into account (on some file systems, "foo.txt" and "FOO.TXT" are the same, on others not). Then what is the extension? Is it `.gz`in `file.tar.gz` or is it `.tar.gz`? What about `report.internal.december.txt`? Your best bet is to iterate over the list, parse the file names, and then do your check as needed.

Comment: I would create a Map with the modified filenames. Add an item if it does not exist, else it already exists. The key would be the name, I do not see where you care what the value is, so leave it the same as the key.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use a HashMap<String, List>.

The keys would be the filenames, and the values would be the various extensions.

So you'd check map.containsKey("filename2"). If you want the full file names, you'd concat the key with the all possible extensions in the value list (i.e. .txt,.xml, etc)

Comment: Please add some specific code in this answer to explain it better

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating the list and calling `contains()` on each `String`.
In each iteration, if the `contains()` returns true, you can increment a counter.

Or your can also use regex to match a pattern instead of `contains()` method and perform even more fine grained matching.
For eg: for filename `abc.txt`, if you search for filename `tx` using contains, you would get true return value.
You can handle these scenarios using regex patter match.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("filename1.txt", "filename2.txt", "filename2.xml", "filename2.csv", "filename3.txt");

        System.out.println(mapToExtension(list));


    }

    public static Map<String,List<String>> mapToExtension(List<String> list){
        Map<String,List<String>> extensionMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String filename: list){
            String[] dotSeparator = filename.split("\\.");
            // Assuming last dot separator is the extension
            String ext = dotSeparator[dotSeparator.length-1];
            if (!extensionMap.containsKey(ext)){
                extensionMap.put(ext,new ArrayList<>());
            }
            List<String> sameExtensionList = extensionMap.get(ext);
            // Add it to the list
            sameExtensionList.add(filename);
        }
        return extensionMap;
    }
```

Once you get a map , you can always check the existing extensions using the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in many ways:

1. If you are not using Java 8 -> *for* loops
2. If you are using Java 8 -> lambda expression which gives the result in one line of code.

**NOTE:** the code has been tested successfully per requirements (see comments for more info)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("filename1.txt", "filename2.txt", "filename2.xml", "filename2.csv", "filename3", "");

        String fileName = "filename2";
        long countWithoutLambda = getCountWithoutLambdaExpression(myList, fileName);
        long countWithLambda = getCountWitLambdaExpression(myList, fileName);
    }

    // Method to get filename Without Extension
    public static String getBaseName(String fileName) {
        int index = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');

        return (index == -1) ? fileName : fileName.substring(0, index);
    }
        
    // if you don't use java 8 and want a simple loop
    public static long getCountWithoutLambdaExpression(List<String> myList, String fileName) {
        long filesCount = 0;
        for (String str : myList)
            if (getBaseName(str).contains(fileName))
                filesCount++;

        return filesCount;
    }
        
    // if you use Java 8 you can achieve it by using lamda expression
    public static long getCountWitLambdaExpression(List<String> myList, String fileName) {
        return myList.stream().filter(p -> getBaseName(p).contains(fileName)).count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or later then you can use *Stream API*:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("filename1.txt", "filename2.txt", "filename2.xml", "filename2.csv", "filename3.txt");
List<String> list2 = list.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.indexOf("filename2") >= 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
list2.forEach(str -> System.out.println(str + "  "));
System.out.println("\nfound " + list2.size() + " occurrences");
```

This code will work for any string you want to search in the `List` elements, just replace the string `"filename2"` with the string you wish to find.

Hope it helps.